# forward message to audit queue for a publisher/subscriber

Tags: nservicebus, publisher, subscriber

I have setup a publisher/subscriber and wanted to send the received message to audit queue. Here my app.config extract

```
  <MsmqTransportConfig
InputQueue="MyPublisherInputQueue"
ErrorQueue="error"
NumberOfWorkerThreads="1"
MaxRetries="5"
/>

<UnicastBusConfig
DistributorControlAddress=""
DistributorDataAddress=""
ForwardReceivedMessagesTo="AuditQueue">
<MessageEndpointMappings>
</MessageEndpointMappings>
</UnicastBusConfig>
```

but my messages are not pushed to the audit queue
my endpointconfig is like that, with both subscriber and publisher interface reference

```
public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Server, AsA_Publisher
{

}
```

any help will be welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have message handlers handling messages at this endpoint?  And can you verify that messages are being processed by these message handlers?

I believe NServiceBus will only forward messages it has user-configured message handlers for, not just anything that wanders by that implements IMessage.  If it did, you'd see a lot of messages in your audit queues for subscription requests and completion responses and other things that are internal to NServiceBus.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want AsA_Server and AsA_Publisher? AsA_Publisher includes all the functionality of AsA_Server. I would say this is why your audit queue is failing.